# How to use {section} in smarty to print an associative array?

Tags: php, smarty

I want to print an associative array using section but I'm not able to do so.Following is the PHP and Smarty code :

PHP Code :

```
  $smarty->assign('$all_latest_news',       $grid_data);
```

In the above code `$grid_data` is an associative array which is assigned to the smarty template. For your information the array looks like this after printing using `print_r($grid_data)`:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [news_id] => 1 [news_title] => News Channel URL [news_link] => http://indiatoday.intoday.in/ [news_added_date] => 2013-02-26 ) [1] => Array ( [news_id] => 2 [news_title] => News Paper Web Address [news_link] => http://www.bhaskar.com/ [news_added_date] => 2013-02-25 ) )
```

Now I want to print this array in smarty template the code snippet for this is as follows :

```
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr align="center" id="tableHeader">
                    <td width="20%" align="left"><b>News Title</b></td>
                    <td width="55%" align="left"><b>News Link</b></td>
                    <td width="15%" align="center"><b>Option</b></td>
                </tr>
                {section name=news loop=$all_latest_news}
                <tr align="center" id="tabledata" bgcolor="{cycle values="#d0e8f4,#96c0d5"}">
                    <td align="left" valign="top">{$all_latest_news[news].news_title}</td>
                    <td align="left" valign="top">{$all_latest_news[news].news_link|truncate:350:" ...":true}</td>

                    <td align="center" valign="top"><a href="manage_latest_news.php?op=edit&news_id={$all_latest_news[news].news_id}">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="manage_latest_news.php?op=delete&news_id={$all_latest_news[news].news_id}" onClick="return ConfirmDelete()">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                {sectionelse}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" align="center"><b>No News Available</b></td>
                </tr>
                {/section}
</table>
```

Using this code I'm not able to print the array values to the respective columns. The column headings getting printed properly. After that the `{sectionelse}` part is executed and the message "No News Available" gets printed.

Actually I want to print the values in array. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the values to variables in Smarty, you don't want to put `'$'` symbol. Change your code to,

```
$smarty->assign('all_latest_news', $grid_data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Edwin Alex. You saved so much of headache and time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I m not begging for reputation. If he accepts the correct answer, it may help for future users who face this problem. I would have asked even for others if they post the correct answer.

Comment: Sushil has been here for two months and a cursory check of his profile reveals that he is well aware of how to accept answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So what.. Nothing is wrong to remind the user to accept the answer

Comment: SO does that for you. Let's stop this now

Answer (score 2):

Change `$smarty->assign('$all_latest_news',       $grid_data);`

to :

`$smarty->assign('all_latest_news',       $grid_data);`

Use this :

```
{foreach from=$all_latest_news item=news name=news}
   {$news.news_title}
{/foreach}
```

Ref: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach